# Accordion Toggle Arrows in Category Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-accordion

i've made a codepen to make this as simple as possible. Open up the tree with the arrows and then click the word to 'select' that category.
http://codepen.io/johnsonjpj/pen/JWebwx?editors=0010

The issue I am having is that when I click a nested category its parents arrows are flipping to the right arrow instead of staying as the down arrow.

The main bit of code i'm working with for this piece is here:

```
var thisParents = $(this).parents('.list-group').not('.list-group-root');
$(".list-group").not(thisParents).collapse('hide');
$(".list-group").not(thisParents).find('.fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-right').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just remove the part of code you've posted and it will work fine not ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki open up with the arrows and then click the word to select, then i think you'll see what i'm talking about.

Comment: Open http://codepen.io/acharki-zakaria/pen/oZQBXv?editors=0010 to see what i'm talking about.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, but in that version when you make a selection it is no longer collapsing the other open categories

Comment: The same thing happen in your version http://codepen.io/johnsonjpj/pen/JWebwx?editors=0010

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki refresh? try opening up all of the categories and then clicking one that is nested at the 2nd or 3rd level, then watch the arrows

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to solve my issue.

```
var thisParents = $(this).parents('.list-group').not('.list-group-root');
$(".list-group").not(thisParents).collapse('hide');

var parentIcons = $(thisParents).prev('.list-group-item').find('.fa');
$(".list-group").find('.fa-chevron-down').not(parentIcons).addClass('fa-chevron-right').removeClass('fa-chevron-down');
```